# How to factor out $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ from $B + A_1BA_1 + A_2BA_2 + A_3BA_3?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A_1, A_2, A_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are diagonal matrices where $A_1 + A_2 + A_3 = I_{n \times n}$. Suppose $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a symmetric matrix. Is it possible to factor out $B$ from $$B + A_1BA_1 + A_2BA_2 + A_3BA_3?$$

Comment: well if $A_1=O,A_2=O,A_3=I$, then $B + O + O +B=2B$ certainly B is factored out no matter what is is.

Comment: You will be able to determine the diagonal elements of $B,$ but off diagonals elements may not be determined, if you allow  some negative entries in $A_i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_k, y_k$ denote the first two diagonal entries of the matrix $A_k,$ $k=1,2,3.$ Then $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$ and $y_1+y_2+y_3=1.$ The $(1,2)$ entry of the sum $B+A_1BA_1+A_2B_2+A_3BA_3$ is equal
$$b_{12}[1+x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3]$$ If the sum in the square bracket vanishes, the entry $b_{12}$ cannot be evaluated. This does not occur when $x_k,y_k\ge 0.$ But if we allow negative values, then we may take
$$x_3=y_3=0,\quad x_1=-1, \ x_2=2,\quad y_1=1, \ y_2=0$$ and the entry $b_{12}$ cannot be determined.

Comment: +1, doesn't $b_{12}$ show up in other terms of $B + A_1BA_1 + A_2BA_2 + A_3BA_3$ though?

Comment: No. The $(ij)$ term of the sum is equal $b_{ij}(1+d_{i,1}d_{j,1}+d_{i,2}d_{j,2}+d_{i,3}d_{j,3})$ where $d_{i,k}$ denote the diagonal entries of $A_k,$ $k=1,2,3.$

Answer (score 0):

Notice $B$ can be taken out common if $B$ commutes with $A_1$,$A_2$,$A_3$, that is $A_1B=BA_1$, $A_2B=BA_2$, $A_3B=BA_3$. and since $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are diagonal matrixes, if $B$ is also diagonal matrix then then it will commute with $A_1,A_2,A_3$.

Comment: If $A_1B = (BA_1)^T$, $A_2B = (BA_2)^T$, and $A_3B = (BA_3)^T$, does that help with anything?

Comment: What does $t(BA_1)$ here means

Comment: no it's not possible to take out $B$ in all cases.